# Why won't this bookmarklet work when I click on it in my bookmarks bar?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I wanted to make a bookmarklet that changes the current YouTube URL to its equivalent on listenonrepeat.com, so I could repeat the video. I have a bookmark in my bookmarks bar with the following javascript:

```
javascript:window.location=window.location.href.replace("youtube","listenonrepeat");
```

Yet it won't change it unless I copy and paste it into the URL bar. Safari 6.

Can be seen here: http://christianselig.com/youtubefix.html

Comment: Try using: `javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href.replace("youtube","listenonrepeat");
`

Comment: Try changing the double quotes (`"`) to single (`'`) and adding `.href` to the first `window.location`.

Comment: Didn't work. The code is available here: christianselig.com/youtubefix.html

Comment: Your URL has some strange stuff in it. Are you sure you wrote it in a programming editor? `javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href.replace('youtube','listenoâ€Œâ€‹nrepeat');`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the url and embedding it into a function, like the code below, makes it open a new window directly into `listenonrepeat`:

```
javascript:(function(win){win.open(win.location.href.replace("youtube","listenonrepeat"));})(window)
```